# mySQL rank order by sum of values in table

Tags: mysql, ranking

I have a mySQL database table I'm using to store messages sent out to people.  Each message can contain points.  I am wondering if there is a query that would sum up all the points per person and order them by rank?

Currently the only way I know how to get the output I'm looking for is to run this:

`SELECT SUM(messagePoints) AS totalPoints FROM Messages`

then store the result in PHP and order the result by totalPoints.  I'm sure there is a way to do this entirely with a query but I don't have a clue where to start.  Hoping somebody can give me some advice.

`Messages` Table example

```
 messageID  |  personID  |  dateOfMessage          |  messagePoints
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 1          |   10       |    2017-01-05 00:00:00  |     5
 2          |   10       |    2017-01-16 00:00:00  |     3
 3          |   20       |    2017-01-16 00:00:00  |     4
 4          |   10       |    2017-02-01 00:00:00  |     6
 5          |   20       |    2017-02-07 00:00:00  |     7
```

Ideal Result:

```
personID |  totalPoints  |  rank
--------------------------------
10       |  14           |  1
20       |  11           |  2
```

If the above output is possible, I'm wondering if it is possible to produce the same output with a date range filter such as only messages from the month of February.

Ideal Result only February messages:

```
personID |  totalPoints  |  rank
--------------------------------
20       |  7            | 1
10       |  6            | 2
```

EDIT:

If it's easier, I ultimately need to display in my application the totalPoints and rank for 1 person (to be supplied by PHP) i.e. just results for `personID = 10`  I need both totalPoints and rank overall and filtered by date.  So maybe 4 separate queries.

Ideal Overall Result for personID=10:

```
totalPoints 
-----------
14
```

and

```
rank
----
1
```

Ideal Result for personID=10 Filtered by February:

```
totalPoints 
-----------
6
```

and

```
rank
----
2
```

Comment: Do you need the rank in the result? You could also just get a sorted result and determine the rank in you application language.

Comment: Actually I like your method by MySQL select queries can have an order by clause

Comment: @Paul if any of the results I'm looking for are possible I ultimately would like the result to contain the rank and totalPoints of just 1 individual person i.e personID 10.  Does NOT need the rank and total points for every person.   Sorry I should have re-worded the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the rank in the result - this is a basic aggregation query:

```
select m.personID, sum(messagePoints) as totalPoints
from messages m
group by m.personID
order by totalPoints desc
```

One way to include a row number (rank) to the result is to use a temporary table with an AUTO_INCREMENT column for the rank:

```
drop temporary table if exists tmp_messages;
create temporary table tmp_messages(
  rank int auto_increment primary key,
  personID int,
  totalPoints int
) as
    select null as rank, m.personID, sum(messagePoints) as totalPoints
    from messages m
    group by m.personID
    order by totalPoints desc;

select * from tmp_messages order by rank;
```

You can ofcourse include fllters in the WHERE clause like:

```
select m.personID, sum(messagePoints) as totalPoints
from messages m
where m.dateOfMessage >= '2017-02-01'
  and m.dateOfMessage <  '2017-03-01'
group by m.personID
```

And you can select a specific user:

```
select * from tmp_messages where personID = 10
```

Demo: http://rextester.com/ASWF7717

Comment: thanks a ton.  That seems to do the trick!  Question for you...when you write `from messages m` what does the `m` do?  I'm still new to mySQL and I've never seen the notation before.

Comment: @Austin it's a table alias. You can access columns with a table prefix like `messages.personID`. But if you give the table an alias, you can use the alias as prefix like `m.personID`. That makes most sense when you use multiple tables in the query and your table names are too long to use as prefix. When you use the same table twice in a query, you must use an alias to distinguish them. However if you just have one table you don't need it. But i'm just used to do it though. Additionally some IDEs like HeidiSQL can help you with autocompletion when you use aliases.

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below code to get the rank and you can use where clause to filter for dates.

```
select personID, SUM(messagePoints) AS totalPoints,@curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank 
from Messages, (select @curRank :=0) r
group by personID
order by totalPoints
```